# This MVC Futures code will not execute. Why is it failing to recognize the System.Data.EntityState?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, razor, asp.net-4.0

I copied the MVC Futures Base templates into my project.  This code will not run.

```
@using System.Data;
@functions{
    bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata) {
        return metadata.ShowForEdit
            && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState) <--This gives an error that entityState does not exist in namespace System.Data
            && !metadata.IsComplexType
            && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Is System.Data.Entity.dll referenced in your project?

Comment: Absolutely. So is System.Data.  Besides, if that were the issue, the program would not build, in my service I use System.Data.EntityState.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `<assemblies>` section of your main `~/web.config` (**not** the one in `~/views/web.config`) file add the following line:

```
<assemblies>
    ...
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</assemblies>
```

This will ensure that the dynamically generated assemblies from the views will reference this assembly so that you can use types from it.

Comment: Even though the enumeration is part of the System.Data Namespace?

Comment: Dang it.  I'm an idiot.  I see now at the very top of the MS documentation, the assembly name is System.Data.Entity.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, if you are not using the EntityFramework in your project (like myself), it's safe to delete that line and avoid the error without including EF.